# Flutter no incia

Tags: android, flutter, programación-móvil

Estoy intentando abrir Flutter, pero siempre me cierra la consola, tan pronto ingreso cualquier comando:

[image: Despues de ese mensaje, la consola se cierra]

[image: Lo mismo ocurre desde Flutter_console.bat]

Esta es la info de mi sistema:

Flutter version --> 1.22.5

Windows --> 8.1

path --> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python38;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\ant\apache-ant-1.9.15;C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271;C:\Gradle\bin;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Agradezco toda la ayuda posible.

Comment: ¿Qué querés decir con "intentando abrir Flutter"? ¿Para qué querés "abrir Flutter"?

Comment: Ejecutarlo, trabajar con el. No me deja pasar de la pantalla que les adjunto.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter no se tiene que abrir , básicamente necesitas un programa como AndroidStudio o VsCode para hacer uso de ese framework y asi poder crear proyectos (apps). Te recomiendo que sigas los pasos de la documentación oficial para poder empezar [Acá podes leerla](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)